# How to create ansible charm in juju

Tags: python, juju

I am trying to create my own charm using ansible. When I do that using "charm create" I get some errors as below:

```
root@charms:~/charms/precise# charm create -t ansible ansi

INFO: Generating charm for ansi in ./ansi
INFO: No ansi in apt cache; creating an empty charm instead.
INFO:root:Loading charm helper config from charm-helpers.yaml.
INFO:root:Checking out lp:charm-helpers to /tmp/tmpJbpY6C/charm-helpers.
You have not informed bzr of your Launchpad ID, and you must do this to
write to Launchpad or access private data.  See "bzr help launchpad-login".
Branched 790 revisions.
WARNING:root:Could not sync: core. Neither a pyfile or directory, does it even exist?
WARNING:root:Could not sync: fetch. Neither a pyfile or directory, does it even exist?
WARNING:root:Could not sync: contrib.ansible. Neither a pyfile or directory, does it even exist?
WARNING:root:Could not sync: contrib.templating.contexts. Neither a pyfile or directory, does it even exist?
root@charms:~/charms/precise#
```

I am using 2.3.4 version of juju and have latest versions of python and ansible installed.

```
root@charms:~# juju --version
2.3.4-xenial-amd64
root@charms:~#
```

I have also installed charm-tools package.

```
root@charms:~# dpkg -l | grep charm

ii  charm                                      2.2.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa2            amd64        Tool for publishing and maintaining Juju charms
ii  charm-tools                                2.2.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa2            all          Tools for maintaining Juju charms
ii  gucharmap                                  1:3.18.2-1ubuntu1                            amd64        Unicode character picker and font browser
ii  libgucharmap-2-90-7:amd64                  1:3.18.2-1ubuntu1                            amd64        Unicode browser widget library (shared library)
ii  python-libcharmstore                       0.0.3-0ubuntu1                               all          Python library to access Juju charmstore data
ii  python-theblues                            0.3.7-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1~ppa2            all          Python library for using the Juju charm store API
root@charms:~#
```

How do I get the missing pyfiles for core, fetch, contrib.ansible, contrib.templating.contexts?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a charm that uses ansible it is not required that you use the ansible template. you can just create a charm with the default template and add the ansible layer. How to do this can be found in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021596/how-to-create-a-juju-unit-for-ansible/1021835#1021835). Make sure you are using the snap package of charm and remove the apt-package.

```
sudo apt-get purge charm
sudo snap install charm
charm create ansi
```

Now your charm will be created and you can start writing your code for the charm.

Comment: I am totally new to JUJU. Operationally, what would be the difference between "charm create -t ansible" and building a ansible layer?

Comment: the template option will just create the basic components to start creating your charm and build it . On the juju solutions github I only found the reactive-python(default) and the reactive-bash. By using the Reactive framework, it is possible to then include the ansible layer. to get the functionality of ansible. At firts sight it looks like the ansible template is not supported any more in the latest charm tools. so using reactive python (or bash) is the only way to achieve it.

Comment: @AchyuthKumarKaranam did my solution work for you to create the charm?

Comment: when i use python as a template to create charm, I did not get the hooks.py file to proceed according to the doc [link](https://charm-helpers.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html#creating-a-new-charm)

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate the behavior of ansible using juju charms. Can you suggest any playbooks or git repos.

Comment: almost all the charms are now written as reactive charms. Creating a charm without any template will give you a folder reactive with you python file in it. this works the same as the `hooks.py` file. Once you build your charm, the hooks will be created and will be triggered depending on which states you set. use this repo https://github.com/chuckbutler/ansible-base to see how to use ansible in your charm. I am not an ansible expert. but you can provide your own playbook when you build your own charm

Comment: @AchyuthKumarKaranam If this was the right answer for your problem, could you please accept the answers, so if people have the same issue, they know that this solved it for you. thanks