# how to create a juju-unit for ansible?

Tags: juju

I need to build a juju unit for ansible alone. I can't find ansible charm in charm store. What would be the better approach?

Comment: The following [page](https://github.com/chuckbutler/charms.ansible) has a nice example on how to create a juju charm using the ansible layer.

Answer (score 1):

There already exists an [Ansible layer](https://github.com/chuckbutler/ansible-base). If you start creating your charm (Info found [here](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.3/authors-charm-writing)) you can add this layer to you `layer.yaml` file. Here is an example of how your `layer.yaml` would look like:

```
includes: ['layer:basic', 'layer:ansible-base']
repo: git@github.com:sebastienpattyn93/ansible-charm.git
```

This will make sure that your charm will install Ansible. If you want your charm to things on top of ansible make sure to use the flag `@when('ansible.available')`

The github page of the ansible-base shows more information on how to use ansible playbooks with this charm.